# Select multiple columns into multiple variables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, select-into

How can I do in **one select** with multiple columns and put each column in a variable?

Something like this:

```
--code here
V_DATE1 T1.DATE1%TYPE;
V_DATE2 T1.DATE2%TYPE;
V_DATE3 T1.DATE3%TYPE;

SELECT T1.DATE1 INTO V_DATE1, T1.DATE2 INTO V_DATE2, T1.DATE3 INTO V_DATE3
FROM T1
WHERE ID='X';

--code here
```

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Your query should be:

```
SELECT T1.DATE1, T1.DATE2, T1.DATE3
INTO V_DATE1, V_DATE2, V_DATE3
FROM T1
WHERE ID='X';
```

Comment: nice thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    V_DATE1 = T1.DATE1,
    V_DATE2 = T1.DATE2,
    V_DATE3 = T1.DATE3
FROM T1
WHERE ID='X';
```

I had problems with Bob's answer but this worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Select Into is used in Embedded SQL like SQLRPGLE. In SQL session like iSeries Navigator INTO clause is not allowed.

Embedded SQL
select col1, col2 into:col1X, :col2X from T1 where ID ='X';

Online session(iSeries Nav or DbVeaver etc)

select col1 as Col1X, col2 as col2X from T1 where ID ='X';

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31235402)